# AWS VPC to Office network with OpenVPN

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, routing, amazon-vpc

I have OpenVPN server running in AWS VPC and able to connect on premises Server to AWS with OpenVPN Client.

Able to ping Instances running in AWS VPC. But not able to Ping On premises server from EC2. Here is the diagram.

```
          (Office Network) 10.24.11.1/24                    (AWS VPC) 10.2.0.0/16
+--------------------------------------------+       +----------------------------------+
|                                            |       |                                  |
|                 OpenVPN Client (Pi)        |       |       OpenVPN Server (Ubuntu)    |
|                                            |       |                                  |
|             +--------------------------+   |       |  +--------------------------+    |
|             |                          |   |       |  |                          |    |
|       eth0  |                          |   |tun0   |  |                          |    |
|      <--+-->|                  10.8.0.2|<--|--+----|->|10.8.0.1       10.2.2.101 |ens5|
|             |                          |   |       |  |                          |    |
|         br0 |10.24.11.15               |   |       |  |                          |    |
|             |                          |   |       |  |                          |    |
|             |       wlan0              |   |       |  |                          |    |
|             +--------------------------+   |       |  +--------------------------+    |
|                       ^                    |       |                                  |
|                       |                    |       |                                  |
|     WiFi Client       |                    |       |                                  |
| +------------------+  |                    |       |                  +----------+    |
| |wlan0:10.24.11.201|  |                    |       |                  | Host 1   |    |
| |                  |--+                    |       |                  |          |    |
| +------------------+                       |       |                  |10.2.1.145|    |
+--------------------------------------------+       |                  +----------+    |
                                                     +----------------------------------+
```

`OpenVPN Server` route :

```
ubuntu@openvpn:~$ ip route
default via 10.2.2.1 dev ens5 proto dhcp src 10.2.2.101 metric 100
10.2.2.0/24 dev ens5 proto kernel scope link src 10.2.2.101
10.2.2.1 dev ens5 proto dhcp scope link src 10.2.2.101 metric 100
10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.1
10.24.11.0/24 via 10.8.0.2 dev tun0 proto static src 10.8.0.1
```

`OpenVPN Client` route :

```
pi@accesspoint:~ $ ip route
default via 10.24.11.1 dev br0 src 10.24.11.15 metric 203
10.2.0.0/16 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0 proto static src 10.8.0.2
10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.2
10.24.11.0/24 dev br0 proto kernel scope link src 10.24.11.15 metric 203
35.176.225.61 via 10.24.11.1 dev br0
```

`WiFi Client` route :

```
pi@client:~ $ ip route
default via 10.24.11.1 dev wlan0 src 10.24.11.201 metric 303
10.2.0.0/16 via 10.24.11.15 dev wlan0 proto static
10.24.11.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 10.24.11.201 metric 303
```

Added route for `10.24.11.0/24` & `10.8.0.1/16` to point to `OpenVPN Server` private IP in VPC route table.

Also have `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in `/etc/sysctl.conf` on OpenVPN server & 
OpenVPN Client.

I am able to ping any ip of the subnet `10.2.0.0/16` from `OpenVPN Client` & `WiFi Client`, but can't ping any ip of the subnet `10.24.11.0/24` from `10.2.0.0/16`.

Firewall Rules on `OpenVPN server` :

```
ubuntu@openvpn:~$ sudo iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

If I ping IP of **OpenVPN server** `10.2.2.101` & VPN tunnel ip `10.8.0.1` from **Host 1** I see packages with `sudo tcpdump -i ens5 -nn icmp`

So Added route for `10.24.11.0/24` & `10.8.0.1/16` to point to `OpenVPN Server` private IP in VPC route table is not working.

After Disabling Source/Destination Checks on `OpenVPN Server` I was able to ping IP of `10.8.0.0/24` from `10.2.0.0/16`. But not `10.24.11.0/24`.

When I ping IP of `10.24.11.0/24` from Host 1, I do see packages goint into tunnel on **OpenVPN Server** `sudo tcpdump -i tun0 -nn icmp` but not coming out from the tunnel on OpenVPN Client `sudo tcpdump -i tun0 -nn icmp`

**Update**

I ran `sudo iptables -I INPUT -s {OpenVPN-Server-Public-IP} -j ACCEPT`, on `OpenVPN Client` then tried to `ping 10.24.11.15` from `Host 1`. 
Able to see packets going into tunnel on OpenVPN Server

```
ubuntu@openvpn:~$ sudo tcpdump -i tun0 -nn icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on tun0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
09:38:42.344238 IP 10.2.2.46 > 10.24.11.15: ICMP echo request, id 12967, seq 203, length 64
09:38:43.344222 IP 10.2.2.46 > 10.24.11.15: ICMP echo request, id 12967, seq 204, length 64
09:38:44.344280 IP 10.2.2.46 > 10.24.11.15: ICMP echo request, id 12967, seq 205, length 64
```

But No package is coming out of the tunnel on OpenVPN Client server

```
pi@accesspoint:~ $ sudo tcpdump -i tun0 -nn icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on tun0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
```

When I ping `Host 1` from OpenVPN Client it works :

```
pi@accesspoint:~ $ ping 10.2.2.46
PING 10.2.2.46 (10.2.2.46) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.2.2.46: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=72.5 ms
64 bytes from 10.2.2.46: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=72.4 ms
64 bytes from 10.2.2.46: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=72.4 ms
```

following is the tcpdump :

```
ubuntu@openvpn:~$ sudo tcpdump -i tun0 -nn icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on tun0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
16:47:06.002682 IP 10.8.0.2 > 10.2.2.46: ICMP echo request, id 2807, seq 1, length 64
16:47:06.003034 IP 10.2.2.46 > 10.8.0.2: ICMP echo reply, id 2807, seq 1, length 64
16:47:07.003467 IP 10.8.0.2 > 10.2.2.46: ICMP echo request, id 2807, seq 2, length 64
16:47:07.003799 IP 10.2.2.46 > 10.8.0.2: ICMP echo reply, id 2807, seq 2, length 64
16:47:08.004003 IP 10.8.0.2 > 10.2.2.46: ICMP echo request, id 2807, seq 3, length 64
16:47:08.004353 IP 10.2.2.46 > 10.8.0.2: ICMP echo reply, id 2807, seq 3, length 64
```

and from `Host 1` :

```
ubuntu@host-1:~$ sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -nn icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
20:47:06.001635 IP 10.2.2.101 > 10.2.2.46: ICMP echo request, id 2807, seq 1, length 64
20:47:06.001694 IP 10.2.2.46 > 10.2.2.101: ICMP echo reply, id 2807, seq 1, length 64
20:47:07.002398 IP 10.2.2.101 > 10.2.2.46: ICMP echo request, id 2807, seq 2, length 64
20:47:07.002445 IP 10.2.2.46 > 10.2.2.101: ICMP echo reply, id 2807, seq 2, length 64
20:47:08.002915 IP 10.2.2.101 > 10.2.2.46: ICMP echo request, id 2807, seq 3, length 64
20:47:08.002961 IP 10.2.2.46 > 10.2.2.101: ICMP echo reply, id 2807, seq 3, length 64
```

`iptables-save` from `OpenVPN Server` :

```
ubuntu@openvpn:~$ sudo iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Tue Aug 13 17:01:18 2019
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [83032:54462790]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [3756:403911]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [84053:7826032]
-A FORWARD -i ens5 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i ens5 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Aug 13 17:01:18 2019
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.1 on Tue Aug 13 17:01:18 2019
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [2350:165593]
:INPUT ACCEPT [276:21608]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [12682:1773625]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [12672:1773673]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 ! -d 10.8.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 10.2.2.101
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Aug 13 17:01:18 2019
```

Comment: i aint know if i did something other but i always deploy the Complete network With /8 and had never ping issues

Comment: Sorry I’m a bit lost, what *can* you ping? 1. AWS OpenVPN server from Office OpenVPN server? 2. Other IPs in AWS VPC from Office OpenVPN server? 3. AWS OpenVPN server from office LAN clients? 4. Other IPs in AWS VPC from Office LAN clients? Also: do you **NAT** the incoming traffic from the tunnel on the AWS VPN server? If not did you set up **VPC route table** to contain *10.24.11.0/24* pointing to the VPN instance? Does the VPN instance permit **IP forwarding**? Does it have **Src/dst check disabled** in the Ec2 settings? That’s needed for routing without NAT. As you can see there are quite

Comment: @djdomi it’s not necessary to use /8 - unless all other settings are in place the cidr block size won’t make any difference.

Comment: @roy the last tcpdump output (eth0 @ host-1) shows that the packets coming from the tunnel are NATed to the openvpn's external IP 10.2.2.101. Can you post the output of `iptables-save` from that host?

Comment: I meant `iptables-save` from `openvpn` aws instance.

Answer (score 0):

> I am able to ping any ip of the subnet 10.2.0.0/16 from OpenVPN Client & WiFi Client, but can't ping any ip of the subnet 10.24.11.0/24 from 10.2.0.0/16.

That suggests that your routing is correct but most likely you've got issues with firewalls. Make sure that:

- the firewall on *ubuntu* permits new connections from VPC to Office. For start something like this should do:

  ```
  iptables -I FORWARD -i ens5 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
  ```
- the firewall on *accesspoint* permits new connections from tunnel to Wifi.

  ```
  iptables -I FORWARD -i tun0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT
  ```

If it still doesn't work start pinging from the *AWS Host 1* to the *Wifi client* and use `tcpdump` on both *ubuntu* and *accesspoint* to verify where the packets go.

1. Verify that the ping packets are coming from Host 1. If not check the *Security Group* and EC2 *Src/Dst checking*

   ```
   [aws ubuntu] # tcpdump -i ens5 -nn icmp
   ```
2. Verify that the packets are going into the OpenVPN tunnel. If not check the *ubuntu*'s iptables firewall.

   ```
   [aws ubuntu] # tcpdump -i tun0 -nn icmp
   ```
3. Verify that the packets are arriving in the tunnel to accesspoint.

   ```
   [office accesspoint] # tcpdump -i tun0 -nn icmp
   ```
4. Verify that they are being forwarded from tunnel to Wifi. If not check the firewall on accesspoint.

   ```
   [office accesspoint] # tcpdump -i br0 -nn icmp
   ```

**Update** based on additional info...

> When I ping IP of `10.24.11.0/24` from Host 1, I do see packages going into tunnel on OpenVPN Server `sudo tcpdump -i tun0 -nn icmp` but not coming out from the tunnel on OpenVPN Client `sudo tcpdump -i tun0 -nn icmp`

That's odd. This sounds like the *accesspoint*'s firewall may be blocking the inbound VPN packets from the *ubuntu*.

Can you try to add this one rule to accesspoint's firewall:

```
iptables -I INPUT -s {aws-ubuntu-public-ip} -j ACCEPT
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: @roy ok, updated my answer.

Comment: Can you ping from office to Host 1 and post the tcpdump output from both gateways while it runs? I wonder if *accesspoint* is NAT-ing the egress traffic.

Comment: @roy Start `ping` from *office gateway* to *aws vpn gateway* and verify that it works. If it does keep pinging and start another ping in the opposite direction - from *host1 in aws* to *wifi client in the office* and see how that goes. Something somewhere is blocking or NATing or not routing the packets in the right direction.

Comment: Ping from `VPN Client` (office gateway) to `Host 1` works, opposite direction Ping from `Host 1` to `VPN Client` (Office Gateway) doesn't work. Tried both together. Also mentioned before Ping packets from `Host 1` to `VPN Client` goes into tunnel on `VPN Server` but doesn't come out of tunnel on `VPN Client`

Comment: *Ping packets from Host 1 to VPN Client goes into tunnel on VPN Server but doesn't come out of tunnel on VPN Client* - are you saying you can see them leaving in `tun0` on `OpenVPN server` but don't see them coming to `tun0` on `OpenVPN Client`?? That's very odd! Are you running OpenVPN in peer-to-peer setup with preshared key? Or tls-client/server? For site to site it's best to do peer-to-peer.

Comment: This is what I think from my test. I was running `ubuntu@openvpn:~$ sudo tcpdump -i tun0 -nn icmp` while ping is going-on from `Host 1` to `OpenVPN Client`. As mentioned in my question.

Comment: @roy it’s hard to tell without access to the hosts. If I had access I would use the `tcpdump` to pinpoint where it breaks and `iptables` to fix the firewall and NAT at that point. Do that and I trust you’ll figure it out. Good luck with that.